# How do I prove "1 not True == False" in Lambda Calculus?

Tags: lambda-calculus

I have to prove "1 not True == False" in Lambda Calculus which is (left side of eq):

```
(λs.λz.s z) (λx.x (λt.λf.f)(λt.λf.t))(λt.λf.t)
```

I come to this step: (which I know is still correct, just brackets could be wrong but I would not know how do get further with different brackets as well)

```
λf.(λt.λf.f) (λt.λf.t)
```

So how does one come from here to `λt.λf.f` (False)?

As far as I know there are no special rules that let me shorten anything like that...

Comment: How do `1` and `not` translate here? And what would `1 not True` mean at all? Anyway, formally, applying $\lambda x$ with $x=F=(\lambda t.\lambda f.f)$ we get   the result.

Comment: From the task `1 = λs.λz.s z` and `not = λx.x (λt.λf.f)(λt.λf.t)`. 
I don't understand what you mean exactly - how do I apply *λx with x* in `λf.(λt.λf.f) (λt.λf.t)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's write $T:=\lambda t.\, \lambda f.\,t$ and $F:=\lambda t. \,\lambda f.\,f$, and $N$ for the middle part: $N:=\lambda x.\,x\,F\,T$.

Then our term looks like
$$(\lambda s.\,\lambda z.\,s\,z)\,N\,T$$
and $\beta$-*reduction* leads it to $N\,T$ since it substitutes $N$ for $s$ and $T$ for $z$ while removing their $\lambda$-prefix.

Writing it further,
$$N\,T\ =\ (\lambda x.\,x\,F\,T)\,T\ \overset\beta\leadsto\ T\,F\,T\ =$$
$$=\ (\lambda t.\,\lambda f.\,t)\,F\,T\ \overset\beta\leadsto\ F$$
where the last step (trickily) substitutes $F$ for $t$ and $T$ for $f$.

Comment: Thanks, I like this 'short way' style instead of writing out the whole term - I think I'll keep this. But I'm still not sure about the last step: the substitution `F for t` is clear, but how to substitute `T for f` - what is the tricky part here? I mean there is no `f` in `(λf.(λt.λf.f))T` I could use for the first `f`, right?!

Comment: The 'trick' is that the letters and their substituted terms are just the opposite, but this is simply because of the order of $\lambda$-bounded variables: in the case of $(\lambda t.\,\lambda f.\,t)\,A\,B$ we replace $A$ for $t$ and $B$ for $f$, and indeed as $f$ is not present in the term itself (only beside $\lambda$), this would $\beta$-reduce to $A$ exactly, while $B$ would be simply ignored. Here we apply this with $A=F$ and $B=T$.

Comment: I see. I didn't know an argument can be ignored if it is not called inside the function but it makes sense if I think aubout it.. Thanks for the explanation!